# Conditional declaration in Apache httpd

Tags: apache, configuration, web-config, user-agent, apache-config

We want to be able to set Cache-Control headers based on User-Agent in Apache

For example, if a User-Agent contains substring `foo` we want to set Cache-Control to 10 minutes. But if not set it to 1 day.

Searching around, I've found `BrowserMatch`, but that seems to only set environment variables:

```
BrowserMatch foo short-live  # Sets environment variable short-live
```

But I would like to conditionally apply a directive like `Header set ...` or `ExpiresDefault ...`

Is there a way to conditionally apply declarations? Something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-control "max-age=86400"
  <IfBrowser "foo">
    Header set Cache-control "max-age=600"
  </IfBrowser>
</FilesMatch>
```

Note, `IfBrowser` is fictional. Is there any real directive that could be used like this? Thanks!

Comment: Reposted to http://serverfault.com/questions/261346/contional-declaration-in-apache-httpd because of lack of response here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, thanks to @muffinista at ServerFault who found the solution:

```
Header set Cache-control "max-age=86400"
BrowserMatch foo short-cache
Header set Cache-control "max-age=600" env=short-cache
```